# when passing object to database, debugger says attribute has variable but when result.hasErrors is printed it is null

Tags: java, spring, debugging, null

I'm trying to add a brewerie object to the database and I am checking for errors before it performs the task. When I go through the debugger, it says it has a variable of today's date, I set it before it checks for errors when it says it has errors, I print out the result.hasErrors and it says the attribute is null.

when going through the debugger
[image]

when the code it uses to check for the error and prints out the error

```
@PostMapping("/addBrewery")
public ModelAndView addAnBrewery(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("brewerie") Breweries brewerie, BindingResult result) {
       Date date = new Date();
    brewerie.setLastMod(date);
    brewerie.setId(1);
     if (result.hasErrors()) {
         System.out.println(result);
        return new ModelAndView("/addBrewery");
    }
```

the printed out error

> Field error in object 'brewerie' on field 'lastMod': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.brewerie.lastMod,NotNull.lastMod,NotNull.java.util.Date,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [brewerie.lastMod,lastMod]; arguments []; default message [lastMod]]; default message [may not be null]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I set it before it checks for errors

No you don't. The error checking is done before method invocation because of the `@Valid` annotation. Calling `result.hasErrors()` doesn't perform the validation, it just returns the result which was assigned when `lastMod` was `null`.

Comment: I set the id before the result.hasErrors() , how come doesn't come up as a null field?

Comment: @GreyWolf18 `hasErrors()` just does `return errors;`, the validation was done before method invocation.